# How do I expose an ICommand property from a UserControl

Tags: wpf

I have a UserControl that is being consumed by my MainWindow app. The UserControl triggers an event after it completes an internal task. I would now like my MainWindow app to handle this event via ICommand.

I assume this could be done by implementing an ICommand as a DependencyObject on the UserControl that would then be binded to by the MainWindow.

Am I far off the mark?

Is there an example to show how I can do this using MVVM?

Thanks

Comment: No you are on the right track. That's how it should be done. Go ahead with creating DP on userControl.

Comment: can you give an example? I tried this and my command is still not firing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way can be to create a behavior attached to the event triggered by your UserControl.
Inside the event handler, the behaviour will execute the `ICommand` of your ViewModel.

Here you can find a custom behaviour attached to `SizeChanged` event of a `FrameworkElement`:

```
public class FrameworkElementSizeChangedBehaviour
{
    public static void SetFrameworkElementSize(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FrameworkElementSizeChangedBehaviour.FrameworkElementSizeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FrameworkElementSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FrameworkElementSize",
                                    typeof(ICommand),
                                    typeof(FrameworkElementSizeChangedBehaviour),
                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(FrameworkElementSizeChanged));

    private static void FrameworkElementSizeChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = target as FrameworkElement;

        if (element == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        if ((e.NewValue != null) && (e.OldValue == null))
        {
            element.SizeChanged += element_SizeChanged;

        }
        else if ((e.NewValue == null) && (e.OldValue != null))
        {
            element.SizeChanged -= element_SizeChanged;
        }
    }

    static void element_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        ICommand command = (ICommand)element.GetValue(FrameworkElementSizeChangedBehaviour.FrameworkElementSizeProperty);

        if (command != null)
        {
            Size args = new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);

            if (command.CanExecute(args))
            {
                command.Execute(args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then attach the behaviour to your UserControl in this way:

```
<MyUserControl mybehaviournamespace:FrameworkElementSizeBehaviour.FrameworkElementSize="{Binding ICommandToBeExecuted}" />
```

where `ICommandToBeExecuted` represents the `ICommand` of your ViewModel you want to call when the event of your UserControl was fired.