# Binding an Event to ViewModel: Extending an article

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've been searching for some information on binding WPF events to commands defined in a ViewModel.

I know there are many frameworks that can do it for me, but I don't want to use any of them, but implement something from scratch to see how it's working.

I've found this article:
http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/hooking-up-commands-to-events-in-wpf.html

and in general it's very good. However, I've got two questions:

1. I'd like to have a command with a parameter and bind the parameter to a property in XAML (like `CommandParameter={Binding ...}`). How to extend the article to handle this ?
2. In my understanding in this implementation to use, let's say, a `MouseDoubleClick` event in two different UI Elements, I need to define two different properties and attach them to each of the types I want to extend. Isn't there a smarter way (i.e. defining an Attached Property once and then use it in all the elements)?

Comment: You will need to use an extended framework to do this. The most common is Expression Blend which offers what you are looking for.

Comment: Really ? Are you sure this can't be done without referencing any external library ?

Comment: You can see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448278/how-do-i-expose-an-icommand-property-from-a-usercontrol/22565054#22565054) to find a sample for binding events to viewmodel. Regarding q1: the behaviour should implement an `Attached Property` containing the `ICommand` parameters to use. Regarding q2: if I understand your needs, you can use just one `Attached Property` shared among multiple commands, but I guess it's clearer and better to define an `Attached Property` foreach `ICommand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using `EventToCommand` behavior from the [MVVM Light library](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/). The related article: [Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)).

Also, there is an alternative to `EventToCommand` behavior (quote from the article):

> Note: You can also use an `InvokeCommandAction` instead of MVVM Light’s `EventToCommand`. This behavior is part of the System.Windows.Interactivity DLL. It is almost equivalent to `EventToCommand`, but without some of the advanced features.

The example of using `InvokeCommandAction` mentioned in the note has been found here: [Executing a command from an event of your choice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/luc/archive/2010/11/18/executing-a-command-from-an-event-of-your-choice.aspx).